# Renaming inner page urls to seo friendly urls using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I want to rename the following URLs to SEO friendly URL.

```
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=1 into http://www.peacockgirls.com
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=2 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/greece-escort
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=3 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/athens-escort
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=4 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/bookings
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=5 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/jobs
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=6 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/contact-us
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=24 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/articles
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?page=7 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/links
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=22 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/aleena
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=40 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/fabiana
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=48 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/sabrina
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=69 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/suzanna
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=63 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/anna
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=70 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/sam
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=61 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/Larissa&Samantha
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=54 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/McKenzie
Change the following URL : http://www.peacockgirls.com/index.php?profile=29 into http://www.peacockgirls.com/profile/valery
```

If you show me 4 or 5 URLs renaming techniques using `.htaccess`, I shall do remaining URLs. I was given this task, but can't do it.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? You didn't post your current setup, so it is not possible for us to point out the issue. I hope you don't expect someone here to make your homework for you... Especially since this is a basic usage of the rewriting mod and everything you need is very well documented and explained, including good, basic examples.

Answer (score 1):

With that kind of tasks I would go for [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).

You could use two separate map text files (for better file management): one for profiles and one for pages (any new file for other type of rewrites).

Your `.htaccess` could be setup that way:

```
RewriteMap userid txt:/etc/apache2/useridmap.txt
RewriteRule ^/index.php?page=(.+) /profile/${userid:$1} [L,R=301]
```

Map text file format is as follows:

```
# Comment line
MatchingKey SubstValue
MatchingKey SubstValue # comment
```

In your case, profiles text file could look as follows:

```
22 aleena
40 fabiana
# more mappings
```

For *page* redirects you can use following approach (map file will be different as well as  `RewriteRule` expressions)

**Before any work, I would recommend going through `RewriteMap` [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) first so you understands the tool i.e. its configuration and usage.**

I hope that will be good direction for your task.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^/greece-escort/?$ /index.php?page=2 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/athens-escort/?$ /index.php?page=3 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/bookings/?$ /index.php?page=4 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/jobs/?$ /index.php?page=5 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/contact-us/?$ /index.php?page=6 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/articles/?$ /index.php?page=24 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/links/?$ /index.php?page=7 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/aleena/?$ /index.php?profile=22 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/fabiana/?$ /index.php?profile=40 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/sabrina/?$ /index.php?profile=48 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/suzanna/?$ /index.php?profile=69 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/anna/?$ /index.php?profile=63 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/sam/?$ /index.php?profile=70 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/Larissa&Samantha/?$ /index.php?profile=61 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/McKenzie/?$ /index.php?profile=54 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/profile/valery/?$ /index.php?profile=29 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess